# Function matrix

Tags: r

Create a function ans(A), which takes as input a 10x10 matrix A, with elements 0 and 1. Function ans has to find the elements that are 1 
and save their indices to a 2 column matrix such that the first column has the row index and the second column has the column index, and return that index matrix.

I was able to find a solution, but its not accepted, no idea what is wrong.. Can somebody help with this?

```
ans <- function(a){
  a <- matrix(sample(0:1, 100, replace = T), ncol=10)
  ok <- which(a==T, arr.ind=T)
  return(ok)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the instructions, you have to first create matrix A and then pass it to the function:

```
set.seed(505)
A <- matrix(sample(0:1, 100, replace = T), ncol=10)

ans <- function(A){
  ok <- which(A==1, arr.ind=TRUE)
  return(ok)}

ans(A)
```

In your solution your creating matrix A inside your function which is not what the instruction says.